# Not showing message is option selected is `Please Select`

Tags: php, html

I have a drop down menu here:

```
        $pHTML = "";

             $moduledrop = isset($_POST['modules']) ? $_POST['modules'] : '';

                    $moduleHTML .= '<select name="modules" id="modulesDrop">'.PHP_EOL;
                 $moduleHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;  
                ....
                $moduleHTML .= '</select>'; 

....

    <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <th>Module: <?php echo $moduleHTML; ?></th>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <p><input id="moduleSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit Module" name="moduleSubmit" /></p>
    </form>
```

My question is simply that if user selects the `Please Select` drop down menu and submit ,it should display the `Please Select a Module` message. But it is not displaying this message. What do I need to change in code below in order to do this:

```
     if (isset($_POST['moduleSubmit']) || isset($_POST['sessionSubmit'])){  

         if($_POST['modules'] == ''){
            $pHTML = "<span style='color: red'>Please Select a Module</span>";
            }else if($sqlnum == 0){
            $pHTML = "<span style='color: red'>Sorry, You have No Assessments under this Module</span>";
            } else{
            $pHTML = "<span style='color: green'>Assessment Successfully Found</span>";

                $assessmentform = "<div id='lt-container'>
                <form action='".htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."' method='post' id='assessmentForm'>
                <p id='warnings'>{$pHTML}</p>
  <p><input id="sessionSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit Assessment" name="sessionSubmit" /></p>
                </form>
                </div>";

                echo $assessmentform;

                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what your whole script looks like and it's hard to tell where code belongs in your example but I'm guessing `$moduledrop = isset($_POST['modules']) ? $_POST['modules'] : '';` is causing the issue.

You need to post all the code all together. It's hard to see what goes where. All I see are two forms and two places checking if code is submitted. I just put this together to give you an idea of what you need to do. The code below works. If you still need help, please post the whole page so I know what I'm reading.

Try:

```
<?php

$pHTML = "";
$moduledrop = isset($_POST['modules']) ? $_POST['modules'] : '';
$moduleHTML .= '<select name="modules" id="modulesDrop">' . PHP_EOL;
$moduleHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>' . PHP_EOL;
$moduleHTML .= '</select>';

if (!empty($_POST)) {

    if ($_POST['modules'] == '') {
        $pHTML = "<span style='color: red'>Please Select a Module</span>";
    } else if ($sqlnum == 0) {
        $pHTML = "<span style='color: red'>Sorry, You have No Assessments under this Module</span>";
    } else {
        $pHTML = "<span style='color: green'>Assessment Successfully Found</span>";
    }
    echo $pHTML;
}

?>

<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Module: <?php echo $moduleHTML; ?></th>
    </tr>
</table>
<p>
    <input id="moduleSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit Module" name="moduleSubmit" />
</p>
</form>
```

Comment: I tried this before I changed it to $moduledrop and it did not work. I will update code to show whole code. Give me 10 mins

Comment: I updated code to show whole code when either submit button is clicked.